# Junit testing a getInstance method

Tags: java

I am trying to test a Registration number class that has a private constructor using Junit. Since it's bad design to test a private constructor, I am testing the getInstance method. However, I have syntax errors, such as:

```
final RegistrationNo reg = RegistrationNo.getInstance();
```

Below is my full RegistrationNo class.

```
public final class RegistrationNo {

 private static final Map<String, RegistrationNo> REGISTR = new HashMap<String,RegistrationNo>();  

    private final int number;
    private final char letter;
    private final String stringRep;

    private RegistrationNo(int number, char letter, String stringRep) {
      this.number = number; 
      this.letter = letter;
      this.stringRep = stringRep;
    }      

    public static final RegistrationNo getInstance() {
      final  Random Rand = new Random();
      int high = 9999;
      int low = 1000;

      int numbers = Rand.nextInt(high - low) + low;

      Character letter = (char)(Rand.nextInt(26) + 'a');

      String stringRep = letter + "" + numbers;

      RegistrationNo n = REGISTR.get(stringRep);

      if (n == null) {
           n = new RegistrationNo(numbers, letter, stringRep);
           REGISTR.put(stringRep, n);
      }
      return n;
    }

    char getLetter() {
      return letter;
    }

    int getNumbers() {
      return number;
    }

    public String toString() {
     return stringRep;
    }
```

Can anyone provide advise on how I can test this?as for the test class, I haven't done much to be honest other that the code below.to be honest I don't know a path forward.

```
package testing;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class RegistrationNoTest {


@Test
public void test() {

    final int number = 50;
    final char letter = 'a';
    final String stringRep;


    RegistrationNoTest test = new RegistrationNoTest();

    //final RegistrationNo reg = RegistrationNo.getInstance();
    }
 }
```

the above code is all I have. I am finding it impossible create an instance of the registrationNo class in any shape or  form.

Comment: Please provide more information about the error you are receiving.  And format your code as well.  It's hard to read at the moment.

Comment: The error I am getting is that RegistrationNo cannot be resolved to a type. Mind you I have used instances of that class in other classes with no issue

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. It should contain the two relevant classes.

Comment: Also add the complete test code. Maybe you are missing an `import` statement?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much, I just realised that I had made a mistake when creating my classes as they were in default package. so I was doing two things from different packages

Answer (score 0):

You can't access a class that is in the default package from a class that is not in the default package. That's one of the reasons you should never, ever put classes in the default package.

Answer (score 0):

Your test resides in a package named `testing`. I assume your `RegistrationNo` class lives in some other package. So you have to import it into your test:

```
import your.package.RegistrationNo;
```